# Javascript Regex Ensure Last 3 characters are digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate that a string ends with *exactly* three digits?

valid:

```
Hey-12-Therexx-111
001
xxx-5x444
```

invalid:

```
Hey-12-Therexx-1111
Hey-12-Therexx-11
Hey-12-Therexx
12
112x
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write:

```
/(^|\D)\d{3}$/
```

which means, "start-of-string-or-non-digit-character, followed by three digits, followed by end-of-string".

Comment: Your rule restrict the input to 3-4 characters. But the input seems to be longer...

Comment: @rekire that is incorrect. He has the correct expression. [Try it yourself and see.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Comment: inhan, that doesn't work.  3x3333 is invalid, but yours lets it through.

Comment: @ruakh Why the edit? You modified the question so it isn't necessarily asking the same question.

Comment: @MichaelMorgan: What do you mean, it isn't "necessarily" asking the same question? Either you think it *is*, in which case, no problem; or you think it *isn't*, in which case, please be more specific: what do you think has changed about it?

Comment: @MichaelMorgan: Oh, but to answer your actual question . . . I found the original "How can I validate that the last 3 characters of a string are digits? If the last 4 characters are digits, that's invalid" to be contradictory, since if the last four characters are digits, then *a fortiori*, the last three characters are digits. So I edited the question to simplify the presentation and remove the contradiction.

Comment: @ruakh Oh, It seems I completely missed that in the original. Splendid edit.